# seaborn countplot group name overlapping

Tags: python, seaborn

I am creating a seaborn countplot. The names of my categorical variable are quite long. The plot is displaying each on one line, so the text overlaps for the different bars. The example looks like the names should continue on to the second line to prevent this, but my plot is failing to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I know answer to this post is late, but this may help others in future. 
I was having same issue, but after doing the lots of finding found "figsize" property of matlab. I'm case categories was more than 10, so I showed on yaxis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7), dpi=300)
-----
sb.countplot(y="native-country", hue='salary',data=dataset)
pt.show();
```

If you want show categories on x-axis by rotating them then below is the code. In this case you may also use "figsize".

```
p=sb.countplot(y="native-country", hue='salary',data=dataset)
p.set_xticklabels("native-country",rotation=30)
for item in p.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
```